# Accessing resource data from JCR repo

Tags: java, jackrabbit, aem, jcr, sling

Using sling resource interface I am trying to get access the data saved as a **binary property** to my JCR node. Currently I am doing it in the following ways , which is returning me a null value.

```
Resource dataResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/testNode/A/test.txt");
ValueMap properties = dataResource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);        

String expected = properties.get("jcr:data").toString(); // null
InputStream content = (InputStream) actualProp.get("jcr:data");  // null
```

Can anyone let me know what is missing , or what is the best way to read the jcr:data property , which is present as a binary data. The dataResource is a **nt:unstructured** one.

the output it shows is :-
**org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.LazyInputStream@4f4c8085**

Comment: Why don't you just debug your ValueMap to see what's in it?

Comment: Sorry, but could you let me ask you a question? Did you try my code yet? How about the result? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

You mention that you were using the Sling resource API rather than the JCR API.  You can adapt the resource to an InputStream directly from a Resource like so:

```
Resource dataResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/testNode/A/test.txt/jcr:content");
InputStream is = dataResource.adaptTo(InputStream.class);
```

As long as the resource is an nt:file or nt:resource, the contents of the jcr:data attribute should be returned as an InputStream.

From there you can read from the InputStream as Tuan suggested in his answer.

You can see an example of this functionality from the following unit test:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/whiteboard/fmeschbe/resource/jcr.resource/src/test/java/org/apache/sling/jcr/resource/internal/helper/jcr/JcrNodeResourceTest.java

Comment: i tried without the jcr:content and i am able to get the resource. .

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, your path should be more like:

```
Resource dataResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/testNode/A/test.txt/jcr:content");
```

I would personally adapt that resource to a JCR Node (*javax.jcr.Node*) and use JCR API from there (*#getProperty()*, *#getBinary()*), but that may be my old school upbringing speaking.

Comment: No , actually test.txt is itself a **nt:unstructured node** , to which its all metadata has been set as its properties. The file content is also present as a property of it in binarydata form , which i wants to read. Hope it makes some sense now.

Comment: Ah, sorry, no idea why assumed it's an *nt:file*. Did you try using JCR API anyway?

Comment: No I am using sling's resource API for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The below code has worked for me:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;

//skip here

Session session = (Session) resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
Node root = session.getRootNode();
Node jcrContent = root.getNode("testNode/A/test.txt/jcr:content");

InputStream is = jcrContent.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int result = bis.read();
while (result != -1) {
    byte b = (byte) result;
    buf.write(b);
    result = bis.read();
}

System.out.println("plain text: " + buf.toString());
```

Also you can find more information at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687689/1521627)

Comment: You should keep a reference to your Binary object to close it when you're done.

Comment: @ehsavoie Are you talking about `InputStream is`?

Comment: thanks  , it worked well , but only after adapting the resource to a JCR Node (javax.jcr.Node) and using JCR API , which actually I was not intended to do.

Comment: I will try to do it with Sling API :)

Answer (score 0):

In AEM, files are often stored as assets. If that is the case, you can adapt the respective resource (the one with `dam:Asset` as primary type) to an asset and read from the file in the following way:

```
InputStream inputStream = resource.adaptTo(Asset.class).getOriginal().getStream()
```

Tuan Dang's method works, but all of the JCR Node methods throw `RepositoryException`.

[Baeldung has a summary on how to convert input stream to a string](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string).