# How to read a xml file from /content/dam in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

I am uploading a xml file to /content/dam/asset folder, this time my workflow would triggering. Inside my workflow java service I need to read XML data

---

### My Workflow  Java Service Here:-

```
public void execute(WorkItem arg0, WorkflowSession arg1, MetaDataMap arg2)
        {
        Session session = arg1.getSession();
        String updatedAsset =arg0.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();
        ResourceResolver resolver;
        resolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
        Resource resource = resolver.getResource(updatedAsset);
        }
```

Comment: google to find a lib

Answer (score 0):

What you got within your `updatedAsset` variable is actually the assets path so

Edit:

you'd need to get the stream out of it which is on the jcr:content of the `original` rendition

`/conten/dam/myapp/myExample.xml/jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content`

your data is in property `jcr:data`

how to get it? with `Node::getProperty().getStream()`

[Get File Out of JCR File Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685959/get-file-out-of-jcr-file-node/4687689#4687689)

Comment: Yes here i will get my asset name[xml name]. but i am asking how to read xml file?